# Why doesn't FileWriter in Java work often but sometimes does work?

Tags: java, filewriter

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    try{
        String content = "hello";
        File file =new File("d:\\test_appendfile.txt");
        if(!file.exists()){
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        FileWriter fileWritter = new FileWriter(file.getName(),true);
        fileWritter.write(content);
        fileWritter.close();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Often, like 90% of possibility, there is nothing in "test_appendfile.txt". However, sometimes, content is successfully written in "test_appendfile.txt". Why?

Comment: I don't know if it is the cause of your problem, but `file.createNewFile();` is simply unnecessary; the FileWriter will create the file itself.

Comment: How do you check whether the append has happened?

Comment: Also try to call fileWritter.flush() directly before closing the stream.

Comment: FileWriter.close() will implicitly call FileWriter.flush(), so that is not the reason. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#flush()

Comment: @ChristophDahlen I won't hurt to try it anyway.

Comment: @JustanotherJavaprogrammer: It's pointless though. Really, there is *definitely* no need for that.

Comment: It is a bit like sacrificing a black rooster to improve your luck.  It is pointless.  I guess you could say it does no harm ... except to the rooster.

Answer (score 4):

There are at least 2 significant things wrong with your code ... and some others that are suboptimal.

### Problem #1

As @Preston points out, `file.getName()` is incorrect.  In your example, it will return `"test_appendfile.txt"`  which is different to pathname that you started with.

Does it make a difference?  Well, it depends on what the JVM's working directory is!  If it is `"D://"` then you are OK.  Otherwise you will be writing a file in the current directory and not `"D://"` which could explain why the file in `"D://` is empty.

You should use `file` as the constructor argument.

### Problem #2

The `close()` call won't happen if an exception is thrown earlier in the `try` block.  If the `close()` call doesn't happen, `FileWriter` buffer won't necessarily be flushed, and you *could* lose output.

You should use *try with resources* so that the `FileWriter` is always closed.

Calling `flush()` explicitly immediately before the `close()` (or anywhere else) is a non-solution.  An earlier exception would cause that to be skipped too.

### Suboptimal code

This is unnecessary:

```
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
```

The file will be created by `new FileWriter(file, true);` if it doesn't exist already.  So the above doesn't achieve anything.

### Some other possible explanations

You haven't shown us the import statements for your program so it is possible that `File` or `FileWriter` are not the standard classes.

It is possible that "something else" is preventing the writes; e.g. `D:` could have a read-only file system mounted, or some anti-virus product could be interfering, or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

You had given the wrong argument to the FileWriter constructor.
Just change the
`FileWriter fileWritter = new FileWriter(file.getName(),true);`
to
`FileWriter fileWritter = new FileWriter(file,true);`